# Trouble with MySQL update joining with a view

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a table with values from a view. Currently I'm using this code:

`UPDATE member, temp_status_date
 SET member.status_date = temp_status_date.status_date
 WHERE member.status_date != temp_status_date.status_date`

which in PHPMyadmin is giving the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'temp_status_date.status_date' in 'where clause'"
What am I doing wrong? Isn't this the correct syntax, according to the official MySQL documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE member JOIN temp_status_date ON
   member.status_date != temp_status_date.status_date
SET member.status_date = temp_status_date.status_date;
```

Comment: It's still returning an error. I added another condition to the ON clause because it needs to update the correct members.
`UPDATE member JOIN temp_status_date ON
   member.status_date != temp_status_date.status_date
   AND member.member_id = temp_status_date.member_id
SET member.status_date = temp_status_date.status_date`
I get the following error: "#1054 - Unknown column 'temp_status_date.status_date' in 'on clause'"

Comment: I was able to determine the issue: the view I had created didn't use a column alias so the name was actually `MAX(member_status_history.status_date)` instead of just status_date.
The update worked after that. Thanks!

`UPDATE member JOIN temp_status_date ON
   member.status_date != 'MAX(member_status_history.status_date)'
   AND member.member_id = temp_status_date.member_id
SET member.status_date = 'MAX(member_status_history.status_date)';`